# VB.NET GroupBy LINQ statement

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

I am having a bear of a time getting this to work. I have a `List(Of MyItem)` called `Items` that have a `OrderId` property on them. From those items, I want to create a list of `Order`s. Some items will have the same `OrderId` so I want to try to group by `OrderId`. I then want to sort by date. Here's what I have so far:

```
Public ReadOnly Property AllOrders() As List(Of Order)
    Get
         Return Items.Select(Function(i As MyItem) New Order(i.OrderID)) _
         .GroupBy(Function(o As Order) New Order(o.OrderID)) _
         .OrderBy(Function(o As Order) o.DateOrdered).ToList
    End Get
End Property
```

This, of course, doesn't compile, and I get the error:

> Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Linq.IGrouping(**Of Order, Order**))' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(**Of Order**))'

I've bolded the part where I think the problem is, but I have no idea how to fix it. Also, it used to work fine (except there were duplicate values) before I added the `.GroupBy` statement. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Basically, I want this:

```
List of Existing Items      Take List and Turn it into 
List(Of MyItem):                 List(Of Order):
ItemId  OrderId                    OrderID 
1       100                        100
2       102                        102
3       100
```

Comment: Do items with the same orderid have the same date?

Comment: the items don't have dates. basically i'm using the items list to grab the OrderIds to make the correct orders, but I don't want dupes. I feel like I'm making it harder than it has to be :\

Comment: So really you just want a list of unique orderids?

Comment: well, yes. but i want to use them to create orders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use group by for this.

```
Public ReadOnly Property AllOrders() As List(Of Order)
Get
     Return Items.Select(Function(i) i.OrderID).Distinct.Select(Function(p) New Order(p)).ToList()
End Get
End Property
```

If you want to order it by the OrderedDate on the order, just add an orderby clause before the ToList

```
Public ReadOnly Property AllOrders() As List(Of Order)
Get
     Return Items.Select(Function(i) i.OrderID).Distinct _
                 .Select(Function(p) New Order(p)) _
                 .OrderBy(Function(s) s.DateOrdered).ToList()
End Get
End Property
```

Comment: thank you! didn't know you could just drop a `Distinct` in there. also, didn't know you could linq like that. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

By putting the OrderBy after the GroupBy, you are instructing it to sort the groups.  A group of Orders doesn't have a single date.  I'm thinking what you probably want to do is switch the OrderBy and GroupBy around; unless GroupBy loses any prior sort order, in which case you'll have to sort each Group.

This also looks wrong to me

```
.GroupBy(Function(o As Order) New Order(o.OrderID))
```

Should it not be

```
.GroupBy(Function(o As Order) o.OrderID)
```

Comment: so i tried this: `Dim orders As List(Of Order) = Items.Select(Function(i As MyItem) New Order(i.OrderID)).OrderBy(Function(o As Order) o.DateOrdered).GroupBy(Function(o As Order) o.OrderID).ToList` and got a similar error to above: Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Linq.IGrouping(Of **Integer**, Order))' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Order))'

Comment: Well, yes, it would do. What you're doing there is trying (with the List()) clause to convert a List of IGrouping into a List of Order. The Integer was just the key of the IGrouping. Obviously now you've edited your question, it's clear that what you were trying to do had nothing to do with GroupBy in the first place, which explains both our confusions

Answer (score 0):

I said F it and used some less pretty code:

```
Public ReadOnly Property AllOrders() As List(Of Order)
    Get
        Dim ids = Items.Select(Function(i As OrderItem) i.OrderID).Distinct()
        Dim orders As New List(Of Order)
        For Each i As Integer In ids
            orders.Add(New Order(i))
        Next
        Return orders.OrderBy(Function(o As Order) o.DateOrdered).ToList
    End Get
End Property
```

If anyone has a LINQier way of doing it, I would prefer to do it that way. Otherwise, I guess this piece of kludge will have to do.

Comment: i went with geoff's method. i'll leave this up here just as an alternative means to the same end.